# MySQL Cannot add foreign key constraint - mismatched charset

Tags: mysql, ddl

The following create statements fail

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `book` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `person` ;

CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `author` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`author`, `title`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`author`)
    REFERENCES `person` (`name`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

with the following error

```
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

and all the data types and field names are all correct. Why is the foreign key constraint failing?

Comment: You do not specify the default charset for the `book` table, so it will default fields effected by character encoding to whatever your DB default charset setting is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, the `DEFAULT CHARSET` clause was mismatched. The second create table statement needs to also declare the `DEFAULT CHARSET`.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `book` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `person` ;

CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `author` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`author`, `title`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`author`)
    REFERENCES `person` (`name`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```